# Text not allowed in element 'ul' in this context using a class after 'ul' tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

```
<div class="tm-gallery-header">
                <h2 class="tm-mb-1 text-center">The Gallery Section</h2>
                <ul class="tm-gallery-filter tabs clearfix filters-button-group">
                    <li><a role="button" href="#" class="active" data-filter="*">Show All</a></li>
                    . <li><a role="button" href="#" data-filter=".nature">Nature</a></li>
                    . <li><a role="button" href="#" data-filter=".campus">Campus</a></li>
                    . <li><a role="button" href="#" data-filter=".people">People</a></li>
                </ul>
</div>
```

By running it in validator it throws the error : "Text not allowed in element ul in this context."

The problem is the class `tm-gallery-filter tabs clearfix filters-button-group` gives me the animation .so I have to use it .
Help me find the way round this error.

Answer (score 2):

If your HTML code is exactly as in your question, the error message probably refers to the "." characters in front of your `li` elements - technically those are text within the `ul` element (and not in its children)...

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is the class

No it isn't.  The problem is the text in the `<ul>` element.  Which [can only contain `<li>`, `<script>`, or `<template>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul).  Remove the errand `". "` characters:

```
<ul class="tm-gallery-filter tabs clearfix filters-button-group">
  <li><a role="button" href="#" class="active" data-filter="*">Show All</a></li>
  <li><a role="button" href="#" data-filter=".nature">Nature</a></li>
  <li><a role="button" href="#" data-filter=".campus">Campus</a></li>
  <li><a role="button" href="#" data-filter=".people">People</a></li>
</ul>
```